# MongoDB, How to query children objects in MongoDB without specifying the key?

Tags: mongodb

For example, I have this structure :

```
{ 
   name:{
        "en":"london", 
        "fr":"londres", 
        "sq":"londra"
   },
   ...
},
{
   name:{
        "de":"barcelona", 
        "sv":"barcelone"
   },
   ...
}
...
```

I would like to know how can I retrieve in this exemple, all cities which name contains "lon", but without specifying the key ("de" or "fr")?

So, not this :

```
db.cities.find({$or:{"name.en":/lon/,"name.fr":/lon/, ...}})
```

But something like :

```
db.cities.find({"name":/lon/}})
-> find in the children of "name, don't care about the key
```

Answer (score 0):

to get this you could create an [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index), which include all fields:

db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" ,
                                } )

and then use `$search` in your query - [more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#search-field)

```
   db.cities.find( { $text: { 
             $search: "lon",  
             $caseSensitive: true,
      $diacriticSensitive: true
    } } )
```